# Internal Server Error in PowerShell cmdlets for Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

On Windows Server 2012 Datacenter with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 installed, I want to run a deployment command but for every commands I get this error: "(500) Internal Server Error".
I first run this:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell
```

and it will work fine and when I check it with get-pssnapin and Get-Help *Crm*, every thing is fine and every thing that I need is registered. but when I want to run a cmdlets command like these, I face the error: Get-CrmSetting or Get-CrmCertificate or ...
For example for Get-CrmSetting TraceSettings it give me this error:

[image: Internal Server Error for a "Get-CrmSetting TraceSettings" command]

How can I solve this problem and error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833084.aspx), you might want to try:

```
Get-CrmSetting –SettingType TraceSettings
```

Here are a couple more items to investigate, from [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689040.aspx):

- To use the XRM tooling cmdlets, you need PowerShell version 3.0 or
  later. To check the version, open a PowerShell window and run the
  following command: $Host
- Set the execution policy to run the signed PowerShell scripts. To do
  so, open a PowerShell window as an administrator and run the
  following command: Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned

Comment: I had tried this. There is no difference between with -SettingType and without -SettingType. In both situations i will face the error.

Answer (score 0):

**Verify the (CRMDeploymentServiceAppPool Application Pool identity) has SQL SEVER SysAdmin permission. This is needed to perform any CRM configuration changes and organizational operations.**

### ***Note: it does not matter if the account executing the PowerShell is a system admin or SQL server sysadmin because these operations are executed via the deployment web service.***

> [Deployment Web Service (CRMDeploymentServiceAppPool Application Pool identity)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699825.aspx#BKMK_D)
>   ....Sysadmin permission on the instance of SQL Server to be used  for the configuration and organization databases.
>   ....

Answer (score 0):

**(500) Internal Server Error**, refers to a HTTP response status code. This means that the Powershell command is calling a URL and the URL is reporting a error.

You need to know the URL to really find out what the problem is. One way you can get the URL, is downloading Fiddler Classic. Once installed, you have to enable HTTPS decryption.

In my case the URL was...

```
https://<my-crm-domain>/XrmDeployment/2011/deployment.svc?wsdl
```

When I ran this URL on the server where CRM is installed, I got an exception stating...

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Application'
```

All this meant, I needed to copy a file, **Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Application.dll**, from **C:\Program Files\Dynamics 365\CRMWeb\bin** into folder **C:\Program Files\Dynamics 365\CRMWeb\XRMDeployment\bin**.

Once this was done, the URL worked and therefor my PowerShell command as well.